# Python: I need some suggestion with the following program

Tags: python

```
list1 = ["experience","as","a","java","developer"] 
list2 = ["B","O","O","B","I"] 
list3 = ["java","developer"]
number = 0
print(list2)
for i in list1:
    for j in list3:
        if(i!=j):
            for l in range(number,len(list2)):
                list2[number] = "O"
                number += 1       
print(list2)
```

Here `"B"` indicates "experience", `"O"` represents "as" and so on.

Expected output:

```
["O","O","O","B","I"]
```

My output:

```
["O","O","O","O","O"]
```

Comment: You want to set one element in list2 based on whether the word is found in list3, but you are setting multiple elements multiple times.

Comment: i am asking for (i!=j) which mean (experience!=java) and so on, if this is true then list2 index should be replaced with "O", not i[0] to j[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correct, you need to do:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] not in list3:
        list2[i] = "O"

print(list2)
```

outputs ['0', '0', '0', 'B', 'I']

Comment: i should not append, the actual question is for example: if(i!=j) i.e (experience!=java), the list which contains b,0,0,b,i should replace with o,o,o,b,i and so on

Comment: Answer is updated, based on your last comment "if this is true then list2 index should be replaced with "O"